# When using an OWIN startup class, how do I dispose of my Castle Windsor container after registering my dependencies?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, owin, castle-windsor

I was having issues whereby my container was not being called in when registered in my global.asax, so I thought that this could be because I am now using an OWIN startup class. I've moved the instantiation of the container to this class now. I'm wondering whether this is appropriate to do:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Namespace.WebApi

public class Startup : IDisposable 
{
    private readonly WindsorContainer _Container;
    public Startup()
    {
        _Container = new WindsorContainer();
        _Container.Install(FromAssembly.Named("Namespace.WebApi.Installers"));
    }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator),
            new WindsorHttpControllerActivator(_Container));
        /// other configuration
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _Container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the [Owino](https://github.com/rebus-org/Owino) NuGet package and use the `RegisterForDisposal` extension like this:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    /// (...)

    app.RegisterForDisposal(_Container);
}
```

or you can look at [how the method is implemented](https://github.com/rebus-org/Owino/blob/master/Owino/Extensions/AppBuilderExtensions.cs#L17-L25) and make your own implementation.

Comment: Worked a treat! Much prefer that approach than making the whole startup.cs disposable

Comment: I don't get it - what is a "_Container"?